# Question on Rational Functions

Tags: functions, rational-functions

[image]

Hi, I'm having difficulty with a math question, specifically part c. Image to the problem linked above.

Comment: Sorry you’re having difficulty. Thanks for informing us, I guess. Do you have a question though?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually just the pythagorean theorem.  Point Q is at $(1,3)$ and Point P is at $(x,\frac{3x}{x-q})$.  $PQ=\sqrt{{(1-x)}^2+{(3-\frac{3x}{x-1})}^2}=\sqrt{{(1-x)}^2+{(\frac{3}{x-1})}^2}$ by algebra.

Comment: Thank you so much! *face palm*